# th:selected for select tag in Thymeleaf not working

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, dropdown

```
<select multiple="multiple>

<option th:each="vName : ${variety}"

th:value="${vName}"

th:text="${vName}"

th:selected="${selectedVariety}"></option> 

</select>
```

In the above code  "selectedVariety" is a string array sent from controller.

I'm not able to bind the select tag on edit.

And this select tag is not a part of entity table so th:filed="*{selectedVariety}" is not working.

Tried th:attr="selected=${selectedVariety==vName?true:false}">

Not working

On using this "th:selected="${selectedVariety}" every option in the dropdown is getting selected.

What may be the solution??

Comment: The `selected` is automatically set by Thymeleaf normally. See [Using HTML select options with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/16/using-html-select-options-with-thymeleaf/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I'm asking to set the selected manually by sending required options from the contoller to the view. I require this mechanism for "update" operation  @WimDeblauwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is selected when the value is included to the String array. You'll need following attribute within your `<option>`:

```
th:selected="${#arrays.contains(selectedVariety, vName)}"
```

It returns `true` (selected) if `selectedVariety` contains given `vName` or false (unselected) otherwise.

Comment: This line of code by you make my code to run like butter. Thanks a Lot @Jakub